# WooCommerce: Replace Add to Cart button with Download button when product attribute price is Zero (0)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce site where I provide customers to download a free version as well as a paid version of the same digital downloadable product. However I have added two attributes "Free" and "Premium" to the product where Free version's price is $0.00. I need to replace the "Add to Cart" button when customer chooses the Free version from the dropdown. Currently the prices change accordingly and I can get to disable the "Add to Cart" button upon selecting the Free option. How can I do this button replacement with the download functionality?

```
function remove_add_to_cart_on_0 ( $purchasable, $product ){
        if( $product->get_price() == 0 )
            $purchasable = false;
        return $purchasable;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'remove_add_to_cart_on_0', 10, 2 );
```

What's needed here is to get the download functionality rather than having button names changed upon selecting the "Free" option and clicking on the newly appeared Download button. So when that Download button is clicked it should download the file without going to the cart or the checkout. And when customer chooses "Premium", the Add to Cart button should appear and product must be added to the cart upon clicking it.

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear…  What is the product type? (How the option free/premium is set for the product?) … As this is based on a client side event, javascript is required. So you should add the generated code html related to the dropdown and the add to cart button in your question… Without that nobody is able to guess and give you an useful answer.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Product attributes added from product add/edit in woocommerce.

Comment: Add the generated html code for the dropdown and the add to cart button it in your question as themes and plugins can make customizations… The generated html code is mandatory for this kind of questions, where javascript or CSS is required…

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried doing this with jQuery? For example:

```
jQuery("#selectElementID").on("change",function(){
    var selectedOption = jQuery(this).val();

    if(selectedOption == "free") {
        // button replacement here
    } else {
        // return add to cart here
    }
})
```

After using this, you'll need to hook it up through `wp_enqueue_script`, assuming the code is placed in an external file (for example, custom.js, or some such).

Comment: May I know the code to place the download button there?

Comment: What element is the parent of your Add to Cart button? I'd go with placing it there, for example, dynamically with something like `jQuery('#addToCart').parent().append('<button id="freeDownload" class="...same as add to cart...">Free</button>')`, and then you'd need to add the appropriate actions to handle the click on that Free button.